# Bash built-in, Variable Assignment through ${var:-""}

Tags: bash, variable-assignment, built-in

Explain please, what does this construction mean:

```
foo=${bar:-"const"}
foo=${bar:+"const"} # not sure about using this construction at all
```

For example:

```
PATH=${PATH}:${BUILD_DIR:-"/SCA"}/tools
...
if [[ ${DEBUG:-""} = "ON" ]] ; then <...>; fi
```

I tried to look it on [ABSG](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html), tried to read `man builtin`, but it's still complicated for me now.
AFAIK, it is smth like assignment to `$foo` some value, with NULL-check of variable `$bar`.

Comment: See the man page under "Parameter Expansion"; the two you are asking about are "Use Default Values" and "Use Alternate Value".

Comment: You've about got it. Just spend 10 minutes doing `echo ${foo:-xxx}` etc. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${bar-const}` evaluates to the string 'const' is bar is unset.
`${bar:-const}` evaluates to the string 'const' if bar is unset or the empty string.
`${bar+const}` evaluates to the string 'const' if bar is set.
`${bar:+const}` evaluates to the string 'const' if bar is set and not the empty string.

The latter two evaluate to the empty string otherwise, and the former two evaluate to $bar otherwise.